# Animate divs according to browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate a certain div in the DOM when the user scrolls to a certain height on the webpage, such as 600px.

Problem is, I'm looking through Google and I can't find anything about it -- it's all about easing.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm looking at jQuery and Javascript documentations but still no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timer;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 600) {
            $("#myDiv").animate({ height: "100px" });
            $("#myOtherDiv").animate({ width: "225px" });
        }

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 700) {
            $("#anotherDiv").animate({ height: "300px" });
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Note the timer here is important otherwise you could end up with literally thousands of `scroll` events being needlessly handled. The timer ensures the function runs once scrolling has ended.

Comment: uhh, forgive me for wanting the answer directly, but which value sets the height so the animation will run?

Comment: It's the `600` in this line: `if ($(document).scrollTop() > 600)`

Comment: awesome. thanks for the help! I'll accept when the timer allows me to. :)

Comment: just an additional question -- what if this was needed for multiple divs inside a DOM? "else if" doesn't seem like its working. Also, I noticed the timer was set so it could run once and conserve resources.

Comment: Check my updated example for how to add additional animations. Basically you need to put the code you want to run on scroll in the `function()` passed to the timer.

Comment: yup, I put the functions inside that part as well -- but I'm talking about additional height points, such as an animate change at 300px for div1, another animate change at 600px for div2, so on and so forth. just different divs at different heights.

Comment: Ah, ok, I've added another `if` condition to cover multiple scrolling points.

Comment: hmm, that's what I did, but it isn't doing anything for the other divs. maybe I'll fiddle with the divs and check the height values for a bit, see what went wrong.

Comment: adding back to this question - i tried an '==' operator instead of '>'... it worked on one of the PCs i executed the code on, but it isn't working on this -- any idea what could be the problem? jquery is working, the script is working -- could it be the checks for the scrollheight that's not registering? For example -- ($(document).scrollTop() == 400) doesn't work, but ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) does

Comment: I'd imagine it does work, but it will only work when the page is scrolled to 400px exactly, and more/less than that (even 1 pixel) and it won't work. You may want to start another question about it if that doesn't help.

Comment: ahh, I see. turns out it might be processing power of each and every single PC, so I decided to go with the '>' operator instead, less precise but more compatibility as some older computers might not hit that targeted value as often as faster ones. thanks for the help again! cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scroll` event (see: [jQuery API - scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)) to detect scrolling and use the value of `scrollTop()` (see: [jQUery API - scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)) to check how far the user has scrolled to trigger further action.